# How to bucket JSON data for a range?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm new to programming so appreciate any help and patience here. :)

We have some data that we're trying to sort by buckets (days of the month in this case) to create smaller sets of data like so:

```
export const Weather = [
  {
    city: "STL",
    month: "july",
    daysbucket: "1 to 10",
    percentages: {
      sunny: "45.5",
      rainy: "20.5",
      cloudy: "10.8",
      partlycloudy: "23.2",
    },
  },
```

Is there a better way than using string like `daysbucket: "1 to 10"`?

The idea is to run some forecast simulations using a probability function that pulls the percentage of the past weather for a certain day without having to list these percentages for each day of the month. So far I planned to get the day of the month and then do some if statements to slot it into a string for 1-10, 11-20, etc. but wanted to see if there was a better way before I get too far.  I have several data sets with a variety of buckets stored as strings but I also have control over the data so can change it as needed.  All of the data is stored in MongoDB.
Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to make calculations and comparisons with the `daysbucket` better to defined it like this:

```js
export const Weather = [
  {
    city: "STL",
    month: "july",
    daysbucket: {
      from: 1,
      to: 10 
    },
    percentages: {
      sunny: "45.5",
      rainy: "20.5",
      cloudy: "10.8",
      partlycloudy: "23.2",
    },
  },
```

Having this structure you can compare it like:

```js
if (day > daysbucket.from && day < days bucket.to) { ... }
```

And so on, note that the in order to compare numbers the values should be defined as numbers, not strings, or if string you need to convert them to numbers (use `parseInt()` or `Number()`)

Comment: Wow thanks for the quick answer! Looks like what I need.  Glad I asked as I was sure I was during it wrong. :)

Comment: If you think my answer is solving your problem you can mark it as correct and/or upvote it to promote it.

Comment: Just marked it correct. It wouldn't let me do that until 5 minutes in. Also says I can't upvote yet as I don't have enough rep.  Will do that as soon as I can!  Thank you for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

I would use an object to do that. Something like :

```
daysbucket: {
min:1,
max: 10
}
```